# What is the name of this visualisation?

Tags: r, bar-chart, visualization

I am trying to figure out the name of this plot that has bar chart on top and lollipops on the bottom which show the inter-relationship of the different categories for the variable of interest.

If you could also suggest any R packages for this would be amazing!!

[image]

Comment: I don't think I've seen that combination named something. I would call it a barplot-over-lollipops. I suggest using `ggplot2` for each plot and `patchwork` for combining them. (Though doing _this_ exactly is just a bit more than simple plots.)

Comment: Another way to look at it (which might inform how to create it) is that it's a lollipop chart (primary) with two marginal barplots (counts on top and counts/percents on left).

Comment: They are called "Upset" diagrams, take a look at this package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UpSetR/

Comment: As other people have said, these are upset plot. The R package ComplexHeatmap actually allows you to make some fairly complex ones, and I use it frequently. More info here: https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/upset-plot.html?q=upset#upset-plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `UpSet` plot, an alternative to `Venn diagram` where you have many categories/sets and very difficult to visualize number of individuals common between sets or of particular intersections. The rows generally represent the sets and the columns or bars indicate intersection size.  If a set is not part of the intersection, a light gray circle or just empty white cell is shown. So, the vertical line connecting sets indicates the column-wise relationships between sets. For example in your plot, considering the first bar from left indicates there are `670` individuals that are `Adult, Male, not survived, and with crew class`. Likewise, the second one indicates that there are `387` individuals that are `Adult, Male, not survived and with third class`. On the left side you see the number of individuals from each Set, of which for example `95.05%`  or `2092` individuals are adult. There are many packages in R that are capable of drawing UpSet plots. for example, [UpSetR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UpSetR/index.html) or [ComplexUpset](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ComplexUpset/index.html). Hope it could helps

Answer (score 2):

An option could be using the `gg_miss_upset` function from the [`naniar`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/naniar-visualisation.html) package which makes it possible to visualize missing data patterns across your data like this:

```r
library(naniar)
gg_miss_upset(riskfactors)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>